# java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver:Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

I have a trouble to connect a Access database.My Operating System is WinXp.I can connect the database through running odbcad32.exe.But I failed to connecting the database through coding following by:

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:driver={Microsoft Access Driver   (*.mdb,*.accdb)};DBQ=F:/JavaWebApp/Proj1/WebRoot/Db/student.accdb","",""); 
Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from StuInfo");
```

Comment: do you have the access  engine installed !

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error, **)** , is missing in your Connection. It should look's like:

```
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)};DBQ=F:/JavaWebApp/Proj1/WebRoot/Db/student.accdb","","");
```

Comment: Thanks.I edited my code as the same as yours,but the errors still apperar.